# Randomly generate a point within a country boundary polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm interested in pulling street view data at random within a country.

I can only figure out how to generate a point within a bounding box.  Often it pulls data from nearby nations.  I'm using a GIS server right now, but I'm interested in removing it from the workflow since it's a pain.

Anybody know of any javascript mapping API that can randomly generate a point within a complex polygon, such as a country boundary?

Phil

Comment: One thing I'm looking at is reversing my workflow and just reverse geocoding a randomly generated point.  So generate a random point within a bounding box, then reverse geocode it.  If the country returned doesn't match the expected country, trash the point and generate another.  However, I'm still interested in not redoing my code, so any help will still be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any practical algorithm to do this for an arbitrary, potentially-concave polygon, and still maintain uniform probability for each possible point.

(I mean, you could pick an axis crossing the polygon at random, find the crossing-points and pick a position from somewhere inside odd crossing-point-ranges. But that would leave some points more likely to be picked then others.)

I would go with the approach of picking a random point inside the rectangular bounding box, [checking for collision](http://www.exaflop.org/docs/cgafaq/cga2.html#Subject%202.03%3a%20How%20do%20I%20find%20if%20a%20point%20lies%20within%20a%20polygon?) against the country's vector data and generating another one on a miss.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm working on now, but I'm hoping there was a way that was easier.

Comment: Yeah, you can do it without making a new geoip request for each point (as in your first comment), though. Hit-checking a point against a polygon is easy. Thought: I guess you could generate a good-enough random point in a polygon by using a randomly-offset rasterisation across the bounding box, picking the start-end ranges along the raster lines in that rasterisation and choosing a random point along the linear sum of all the ranges. As you increase the number of lines you make the imperfectly-uniform probability much less obvious than the example with one axis line.

Comment: (OTOH this is unlikely to be any faster than the discard-and-try-again method.)